# Did Alderaan have any weapons?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, princess-leia

From the script of this scene:

> Tarkin: In a way, you have determined the choice of the planet that will be destroyed first. Since you are reluctant to provide us with the location of the Rebel base, I have chosen to test this station's destructive power on your home planet of Alderaan.
>
> Leia: **No! Alderaan is peaceful. We have no weapons.** You can't possibly–

[image]
Hilarious gifs like this one notwithstanding, was Leia telling the truth?

### Did Alderaan really have no weapons?  If not, why?

Comment: Which part of "We have no weapons" was unclear? Are you accusing her of lying?

Comment: Anybody have access to the novelisation? I can't find mine, but stuck in my brain is some scene in there where some underling tells Tarkin post-destruction about having found scan data or order forms or whothehellknowswhat showing that Alderaan had or was in the process of installing planetary weaponry. As a result the Grand Moff feels totally justified. It's been so long, for all I know I'm getting 40 years of scifi reading mixed up. :(

Comment: @Richard Wait, you sound like Leia's attorney! What if we *are* accusing her of lying? What if she *did* lie? Never trust an Alderaanian, I always say, I've spent too much time in SWTOR on that planet. You can't trust *anybody* there, the noble houses there are worse than GoT!

Comment: @Marakai - From the novelisation "*Nonetheless, he turned to them and insinuated himself into their conversation. “The defense systems on Alderaan, despite the Senator’s protestations to the contrary, were as strong as any in the Empire. I should conclude that our demonstration was as impressive as it was thorough.”*"

Comment: *"Tarkin turned to him, nodding. “The Senate is being informed of our action at this very moment. Soon we will be able to announce the extermination of the Alliance itself, as soon as we have dealt with their main military base. Now that their main source of munitions, Alderaan, has been eliminated, the rest of those systems with secessionist inclinations will fall in line quickly enough, you’ll see.”*

Comment: @Richard FTW! Thanks!

Comment: @Richard - Yes.  Yes I am.  She also said the *Tantive IV* was a consular ship on a diplomatic mission.  **If that was a consular ship, where was the Ambassador?**

Comment: @WadCheber - *She* (Leia) was the ambassador, a representative of her government.

Comment: @Richard - She was part of the rebel alliance and a TRAITOR - **TAKE HER AWAY!**

Comment: One guy had a pocket knife. He was promptly exiled for life.

Comment: @WadCheber - Silence, Rebel Scum!

Comment: Alderan shot first... I get it...

Comment: Don't forget how much the Imps loved their propaganda mills. That business about Alderaan having weapons was rather conveniently brought up after the evidence was blasted.

Comment: If you have weapons, then when a Death Star is knocking on your door is a pretty good time to break them out.

Comment: Well, it had a Death Star... kinda....

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere that Alderaan or Alderaan-based companies were a major supplier or builder of weapons in the past.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook confirms Leia's statement that Alderaan is without planetary weapons and explains why.

> *The planet holds true to its peaceful beliefs, refusing armaments even
>   as conflict troubles the Galaxy*